# IIS + ASP.NET Core 6 + Hosting Pack resulting in default document/directory listing error

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I'm attempting to get IIS to serve our ASP.NET 6 web application, but every time it complains of needing a default document. If I run the exe (kestrel) one it will serve it, but we want it to be hosted by IIS with the other components of the site.

I installed the 6.0.10 runtime w/ hosting package and these are the results when listing runtimes:

[image]

When looking at the site modules, I think it should have what is needed (think the AspNetCoreModuleV2 one handles the compiled routing scenario?):

[image]

Have rebooted the server and the app pool specifically, set to No Managed Code, and whenever I attempt to load the page at the localhost level, I get:

[image]

The views are compiled so I don't think I even need IIS to open views locally in any capacity.

Comment: A) Do you have a web.config configured to server up the app? [msdn: web.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/web-config?view=aspnetcore-6.0) B) Is your app pool set up correctly? re: "No Managed Code".

Comment: A) it existed in the /publish/ folder (generated in bin/release/net6.0). Just tried copying and pasting it directly to net6.0 and recycling the app pool and restart site. Gives same message. B) App Pool is setup for No Managed Code + Integrated

Comment: Right-click VS project and select "Publish". Then create a local folder deployment (can be any folder on your machine). Take the output of the deployment and then replace whatever is in your IIS site with the contents of the local deployment.

Comment: I'm actually using VSCode with this instead of Visual Studio. The command I was running is "dotnet build --configuration Release" would that be alright or is there a publish command for vscode?

Comment: You want to use the [dotnet publish command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish) with the CLI.

Comment: That was it. Was able to use build for Web Forms and just continued that but publish has it working. Create an answer and I'll mark it. Thanks Metro Smurf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you've posted ticks off the major deployment steps for hosting a .NET 6 project on IIS:

- Installed the .NET Core 6.0 Runtime Windows Hosting Bundle
- Set up the IIS app pool with "No Managed Code"
- Rebooted the server: *"Have you turned it off and on again?"*

After our exchange in the comments, the only thing that appeared to be missing is to use the .NET publish command; not the build command.

When deploying to IIS, you'll want to run the [dotnet publish command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish) and then deploy those artifacts to your IIS server. From the docs:

> The `dotnet publish` command's output is ready for deployment to a hosting system (for example, a server, PC, Mac, laptop) for execution. It's the only officially supported way to prepare the application for deployment. Depending on the type of deployment that the project specifies, the hosting system may or may not have the .NET shared runtime installed on it.

You also may want to review: [Publish .NET apps with the .NET CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli).